# what can I do with hadoop and elasticsearch together?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

I'm reading about hadoop with elasticsearch, so I'm confused about how it works.

I guess in this case elasticsearch is substitute for HDFS/Hbase, so I could write hadoop jobs to get and process data in elasticsearch.

Is this correct?

If yes, does this works for Hive and Pig too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use elasticsearch in Hadoop like :

- Input and output for MapReduce
- Input (storage) for Hive and Pig
- Write and read directly in ElasticSearch with Cascading